# NodeJS: Capturing a stereo PCM wave stream into mono AudioBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, web-audio-api, alsa

I'm recording audio from nodejs using [node-microphone](https://github.com/MexXxo/node-microphone) (which is just a javascript interface for arecord), and want to store the stream chunks in an `AudioBuffer` using [web-audio-api](https://github.com/audiojs/web-audio-api) (which is a nodejs implementation of the Web Audio API).

My audio source has two channels while my `AudioBuffer` has only one (in purpose).

This is my working configuration for recording audio with arecord through my USB sound card (I'm using a Raspberry pi 3 running on Raspbian buster):

```
arecord -D hw:1,0 -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 44100
```

Running this command with an output path and playing the resulting wav file with aplay works just fine. So node-microphone is able to record audio with these parameters, and at the end I get a nodejs readable stream flowing wave data.

***But***

I'm struggling doing the bridge from the stream chunks (`Buffer` instances) to the `AudioBuffer`. More precisely; I'm not sure of the format of the incoming data, not sure of the destination format, and not sure of how I would do the conversion whatever:

The stream chunks are `Buffer`s so they also are `Uint8Array`s. Regarding my configuration, I guess they are binary representations of 16 bits signed integers (little endian, I don't know what it means).

The `AudioBuffer` holds multiple buffers (one per channel, so only one in my case) that I can access as `Float32Array`s by calling `AudioBuffer.prototype.getChannelData()`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) also says:

> The buffer contains data in the following format: non-interleaved IEEE754 32-bit linear PCM with a nominal range between -1 and +1, that is, 32bits floating point buffer, with each samples between -1.0 and 1.0.

The point is to find what I have to extract from the incoming `Buffer`s and how I should transform it so it's suitable for the `Float32Array` destination (and remains valid wave data), knowing that the audio source is stereo and the `AudioBuffer` isn't.

My best contender so far was the `Buffer.prototype.readFloatLE()` method whose name looks like it would solve my problem, but this wasn't a success (just noise).

My first try (before doing research) was just to naively copy buffer data to `Float32Array` and interleaving indexes to handle stereo/mono conversion. Obviously it mostly produced noise but I could hear some of the sound I recorded (incredibly distorted but surely present) so I guess I should mention that.

This is a simplified version of my naive try (I'm aware this is not meant to work well, I just include it in my question as a base of discussion):

```js
import { AudioBuffer } from 'web-audio-api'
import Microphone from 'node-microphone'

const rate = 44100
const channels = 2 // Number of source channels

const microphone = new Microphone({ // These parameters result to the arecord command above
  channels,
  rate,
  device: 'hw:1,0',
  bitwidth: 16,
  endian: 'little',
  encoding: 'signed-integer'
})

const audioBuffer = new AudioBuffer(
  1, // 1 channel
  30 * rate, // 30 seconds buffer
  rate
})

const chunks = []
const data = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0) // This is the Float32Array
const stream = microphone.startRecording()

setTimeout(() => microphone.stopRecording(), 5000) // Recording for 5 seconds

stream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))

stream.on('close', () => {
  chunks.reduce((offset, chunk) => {
    for (var index = 0; index < chunk.length; index += channels) {
      let value = 0

      for (var channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++) {
        value += chunk[index + channel]
      }

      data[(offset + index) / channels] = value / channels // Average value from the two channels
    }

    return offset + chunk.length // Since data comes as chunks, this offsets AudioBuffer's index
  }, 0)
})
```

I would be really grateful if you could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the input stereo signal is coming as 16 bits signed integers, interleaving left and right channels, meaning that the corresponding buffers (8 bits unsigned integers) have this format for a single stereo sample:

```
[LEFT ] 8 bits (LSB)
[LEFT ] 8 bits (MSB)
[RIGHT] 8 bits (LSB)
[RIGHT] 8 bits (MSB)
```

Since arecord is configured with *little endian* format, the *Least Significant Byte* (LSB) comes first, and the *Most Significant Byte* (MSB) comes next.

The `AudioBuffer` single channel buffer, represented by a `Float32Array`, expects values between `-1` and `1` (one value per sample).

So to map values from the input `Buffer` to the destination `Float32Array`, I had to use the `Buffer.prototype.readInt16LE(offset)` method incrementing the bytes `offset` parameter by 4 each sample (2 left bytes + 2 right bytes = 4 bytes), and interpolating input values from range `[-32768;+32768]` (16 bits signed integer range) to range `[-1;+1]`:

```js
import { AudioBuffer } from 'web-audio-api'
import Microphone from 'node-microphone'

const rate = 44100
const channels = 2 // 2 input channels

const microphone = new Microphone({
  channels,
  rate,
  device: 'hw:1,0',
  bitwidth: 16,
  endian: 'little',
  encoding: 'signed-integer'
})

const audioBuffer = new AudioBuffer(
  1, // 1 channel
  30 * rate, // 30 seconds buffer
  rate
})

const chunks = []
const data = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0)
const stream = microphone.startRecording()

setTimeout(() => microphone.stopRecording(), 5000) // Recording for 5 seconds

stream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))

stream.on('close', () => {
  chunks.reduce((offset, chunk) => {
    for (var index = 0; index < chunk.length; index += channels + 2) {
      let value = 0

      for (var channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++) {
        // Iterates through input channels and adds the values
        // of all the channel so we can compute the
        // average value later to reduce them into a mono signal

        // Multiplies the channel index by 2 because
        // there are 2 bytes per channel sample

        value += chunk.readInt16LE(index + channel * 2)
      }

      // Interpolates index according to the number of input channels
      // (also divides it by 2 because there are 2 bytes per channel sample)
      // and computes average value as well as the interpolation
      // from range [-32768;+32768] to range [-1;+1]
      data[(offset + index) / channels / 2] = value / channels / 32768
    }

    return offset + chunk.length
  }, 0)
})
```